# Qt how to pass valid socketDescriptor to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets

I trying to implement threaded server application which runs 1 processing thread per physical CPU Core/Thread.
The goal is to spread all incoming connections over threads, threads must close connections if needed.
My server implementation is based on **QTcpServer** and reimplements **incomingConnection** funtion, which checks current connection counts of all underlayer Threads and pass **qintptr socketDescriptor** to thread-class function, which is only add this **qintptr** to list of "pending sessions".
In **thread::run** I have infinite loop, this loop is checking list of "pending sessions" and if it is not empty - create new **QTcpSocket** and pass **socketDescriptor** to **setSocketDescriptor** function of newly created Socket object.
I see in console log what i passing valid **socketDescriptor** (same value as i had in **incomingConnection** function), *[wrong information, I just missed "!" in my "if" statement: but setSocketDescriptor failed with error "Unknown Error"]* edit: **setSocketDescriptor** function succeed, but Socket dont accept any data and even if connection closed by remote client, **::socketDescriptor()** returns initially passed value (must be -1 after "connection lost" type situation).

Question is: what actually happened with socketDescriptor between calls of incomingConnection and next cycle of thread's loop?
I found many examples where socketDescriptor successfuly passed to Thread object's constructor function (so socketDescriptor is "used" immediately after incomingConnection), but I need to create Socket objects later in Thread life-cycle.
I can setup QTcpSocket right in incomingConnection function and it will work. I will try to do so and pass QTcpSocket to desired thread via moveToThread(), but even if it works, I want to know why my current implementation is failed.

code (Main Thread accept connection):

```
void Server::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)

{
    qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<"sd:"<<socketDescriptor;

    ServerThread* t = threads[0];

    // find thread with lowest connection count
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < CPU_Count; i++)
    {
        if (threads[i]->getConnectionCount() < t->getConnectionCount())
            t = threads[i];
    }

    t->newConnection(socketDescriptor);
}
```

code (pass socketDescriptor to Thread object for further use):

```
void ServerThread::newConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
// QList<qintptr> sessions_pending;
    sessions_pending.append(socketDescriptor);
}
```

code (trying to create QTcpSocket in ServerThread::run):

```
    if (sessions_pending.count())
    {
        foreach (qintptr sd, sessions_pending)
        {
            qDebug()<<"create socket, descriptor : "<<sd; // show same value as incomingConnection

            QTcpSocket* newSocket = new QTcpSocket(0);
            if (!newsocket->setSocketDescriptor(sd))
                qDebug()<<"Error during socket creation : "<<s->socket->errorString()<<s->socket->error();
            // output: "Unknown error" QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError

            // .. here was code which store QTcpSocket and so on ..
        }
        sessions_pending.clear();
    }
```

Comment: If someone interested. I drop my attempt to bring it to life and reimplement networking from 0. In new implementation I have QTcpServer in Main Thread who accepts connections, allocates QTcpSocket objects and calls setSocketDescriptor. But I doing all job with these sockets from separated Worker Threads (pass socket object to Decision Making Units, which exicts in one of QThread's context). Since read/write calls comes from other threads, I assume what all must work fine with any number of CPU Cores... But not absolutely sure atm. When I need to delete socket, I just call deleteLater on it.

Comment: The problem of new solution is what all Network Output must be done from Main thread (which allocate Server and Sockets). I can Read from Sockets from Worker Threads, but _not_ Write. Google tells what it is limitation of Qt's IO design. I dont know how to solve this and can only hope what it will be Ok to do all decision making in W.Threads and Send packets from M.Thread.

Comment: May be a bit late, but I try to accomplish something similar. Did you try setting up a worker in a QThread and use ``QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`` with a ``Qt::QueuedConnection``?

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what for you need "pending sessions" in this case.

This is one of the possible ways to forward socket descriptor through `incomingConnection()` and `QTcpSocket`. We create SocketThread object, which inherits QThread

```
void Server::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    SocketThread *thread = new SocketThread(handle);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    thread->start();
}
```

In contructro we initialize private member m_socketDescriptor:

```
SocketThread::SocketThread(qintptr descriptor, QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent),
      m_socketDescriptor(descriptor)
{

}
```

If we inherit `QThread` class, so we must override `run()` method.

```
void SocketThread::run()
{
    m_socket = new QTcpSocket;
    m_socket->setSocketDescriptor(m_socketDescriptor);

    connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),    this, SLOT(onReadyRead()),    Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onDisconnected()), Qt::DirectConnection);

    exec();
}
```

At run as you can see we init `QTcpSocket`, set socket descriptor, connect `readyRead()` and `disconected()` signals with relevant slots and start event loop.

At `readyRead()` we read data from socket, then disconect from host:

```
void SocketThread::onReadyRead()
{
    // get data from socket
    m_socket->disconnectFromHost();
}
```

At `onDisconnected()` just close your socket and leave from event loop:

```
void SocketThread::onDisconnected()
{
    m_socket->close();
    quit();
}
```

Its one of the possible ways.

I hope you will be able to adapt my code to your project. Best regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But as I said before: I found many examples where socketDescriptor successfuly passed to Thread object's constructor function (so socketDescriptor is "used" immediately after incomingConnection), but I need to create Socket objects later in Thread life-cycle. I dont want to have 1 thread per connection. I need 1 thread per CPU (real processing thread). Currently I reimplement everything to create QTcpSocket objects in main thread and pass it to Worker threads. It works as I already expected in initial post. But I still dont understand whats the problem with my first try.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry. May be you need to look towards QThreadPool? Also, i see it only now at your part of code `if (!newsocket.setSocketDescriptor(sd))` but you have pointer to QTcpSocket, so use -> operator.

Comment: Yeah, I made a typo while trying to made short version of my code as an example. Thanks, fixed now. I dont see how QThreadPool can help me here. It can help to manage a lot of Threads, but I dont think what it is reasonable to create individual Thread for each Connection (I can have more than 10k connections at the same time). Currently I ended up with solution where network IO is made in Main Thread, but Packets En-/Decryption, Parsing and Decision Making (for each single Session) is made in Worker Threads (1 per CPU Core). I added some comments to first post also. Thanks for participation!